# Google Analytics: Making an Experiment respond to earnings

Tags: google-analytics, ab-testing, google-experiments

I'm currently in the process of creating an A/B test in Google Analytics (aka an "Experiment"). It's for a ticket purchasing page where there are several levels of tickets for sale (eg. Standard, Premium, First Class, etc).

We want the winning page variant to be the one that earns the most *money*, not necessarily just the one that triggers the most Goals (ie. number of successful transactions).

For example:

**Variant A**
Sales: 20
Total Sales Value: $100
(*20 x Standard tickets*)

**Variant B**
Sales: 5
Total Sales Value: $1000
(*5 x First Class tickets*)

We would want Variant B to win, even though the number of events triggered (aka "Goals") was higher with Variant A.

I cannot find anywhere discussing this issue, but surely the average value of an Event should factored into the success of a Variant?

We have the Goal configured like this at the moment:

[image]

One thing I've considered is increasing the Value threshold to be larger than the average sale, so the Goal doesn't trigger unless the page performs better than average. This isn't ideal for obvious reasons, though.

Is there another way?